# Loading image from https url in android

Tags: android, https

could not able to load image from an https url in android.
below is the code.

```
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        //imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.scan);

        URL url = new URL("https://idw.ideaservices.net/files/11258/272.jpg");
        InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
        imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Below is the xml for the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any other image from https url from  flickr gets loaded but not the one I have specified. 
Any pointers to make it work would help us immensely.thanks.

Comment: Whats your error log telling?

Comment: Try this : http://androiddevelopmentworld.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-call-https-webservices-in-android.html

Comment: I just get this message in log,  `request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol`

Answer (score 0):

Use This..it might be helpful to you..

```
    public class image extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("https://idw.ideaservices.net/files/11258/272.jpg");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```